# Problem with creating a pygame object inside a class

Tags: python, pygame

So this is the code that I created, it's going to be a simple 2D game. I was trying to experiment with classes while making another game to make it more functional and organized. But the problem is that when I run the code and try to move the player in the main() function the position of the player doesn't change when Im pressing the buttons.

```
import pygame as pg

\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Colors

RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Constants

FPS = 60
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1400, 900
P_VEL = 10
\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Variables

\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Objects

\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Fonts

\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Sprites

\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Sounds

\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WINDOW = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("Game Project")

\#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, x_cord, y_cord, width, height):
        self.xc = x_cord
        self.yc = y_cord
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.hero = pg.Rect(self.xc,self.yc,self.width,self.height)

    def player_movement(self, keys_pressed):
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_d]:
            self.xc += P_VEL
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_a]:
            self.xc -= P_VEL
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_w]:
            self.yc -= P_VEL
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_s]:
            self.yc += P_VEL
    
    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.rect(WINDOW, GREEN, self.hero)

player = Hero(500,400,40,60)

def gravis():
    WINDOW.fill(BLACK)
    player.draw()
    pg.display.update()

def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False

        keys_pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
        
        player.player_movement(keys_pressed)
    
        gravis()

main()
```

I tried searching for answers on youtube and looking through the code but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying out your program, the button pressing is updating the x an y coordinates of your object; however, the hero attribute is not changed as it is defined and built via the pg.Rect() function.  When I added a line of code in the draw() function, there was a response and the rectangle moved.

```
    def draw(self):
        self.hero = pg.Rect(self.xc,self.yc,self.width,self.height)     # Redefined the rectangle's size and location
        pg.draw.rect(WINDOW, GREEN, self.hero)
```

Give that a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `self.xc` or `self.yc`, the position stored in `self.hero` does not change. However, `self.hero` is used to draw the rectangle. Therefore, you must update `self.hero` after changing `self.xc` or `self.yc`:

```py
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, x_cord, y_cord, width, height):
        self.xc = x_cord
        self.yc = y_cord
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.hero = pg.Rect(self.xc,self.yc,self.width,self.height)

    def player_movement(self, keys_pressed):
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_d]:
            self.xc += P_VEL
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_a]:
            self.xc -= P_VEL
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_w]:
            self.yc -= P_VEL
        if keys_pressed[pg.K_s]:
            self.yc += P_VEL

        self.hero.x = self.xc                          # <---
        self.hero.y = self.yc
    
    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.rect(WINDOW, GREEN, self.hero)
```